# How to remove special characters while loading a csv in R?

Tags: r, csv, quotes, read.csv

I have this similar problem: [read.csv warning 'EOF within quoted string' prevents complete reading of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414776/read-csv-warning-eof-within-quoted-string-prevents-complete-reading-of-file)

That is, when I load a csv R says:

```
Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
EOF within quoted string
```

I can get rid of this error by applying: quotes="" to read.csv

But the main problem still exists, only 22111 rows of 689233 in total are read into R. I would like to try removing all special characters from the csv to see if this clears the problem.

Related I found this: [How to remove specific special characters in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641522/how-to-remove-specific-special-characters-in-r)

But is there a way to do it in read.csv, that is in the phase when I'm reading in the file?

Comment: Are you certain that your input file is well-formed, meaning that all 689,233 rows have the same number of columns?  `read.csv` (which is a wrapper around `read.table`) is somewhat sensitive and can die for bad input files.

Comment: I don't think you can do it within read.csv! I believe it is even better here to  not use R and use something like `awk` or other Linux text post-processing commands.

Comment: @ElinaJ Could you post the first 2 rows along with rows 22111 and 22112 from your input csv file?

Comment: I'm afraid it's sensitive data and it's not possible to post... I tried deleting rows 21611-22111 and now I got 230,168 rows to load...

Comment: You can likely solve it by using read.table with option `encoding`.

Comment: What should I set the encoding to?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `fread` from `data.table`? It can optimize the task and likely deal with some common issues. As you haven't provide any piece of data, I'm giving a silly example:

```
> fread('col1,col2\n5,"4\n3"')
   col1 col2
1:    5 4\n3
```

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a special charcter. There was a → (arrow, hexadecimal value 0x1A) on line 22,112.
After deleting the arrow I get the data to load normally!

Answer (score 0):

Solution of datatable expord csv with special chahracters 
Find charset from 
 https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/buttons.html5.js
or
 https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js

and change it to 'UTF-8-BOM'from 'UTF-8'

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.