# Remove special characters from entire dataframe in R

Tags: r, data-science, data-cleaning

**Question:**

How can you use R to remove all special characters from a dataframe, quickly and efficiently?

**Progress:**

This SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641522/how-to-remove-specific-special-characters-in-r/21641569) details how to remove special characters. I can apply the gsub function to single columns (images 1 and 2), but not the entire dataframe.

**Problem:**

My dataframe consists of 100+ columns of integers, string, etc. When I try to run the gsub on the dataframe, it doesn't return the output I desire. Instead, I get what's shown in image 3.

```
df <- read.csv("C:/test.csv")
dfa <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", df$a) #this works on a single column
dfb <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", df$b) #this works on a single column
df_all <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", df) #this does not work on the entire df
View(df_all)
```

**df** - This is the original dataframe:

[image: Original dataframe]

**dfa** - This is gsub applied to column b. Good!

[image: gsub applied to column b]

**df_all** - This is gsub applied to the entire dataframe. Bad!

[image: gsub applied to entire dataframe]

**Summary:**

Is there a way to gsub an entire dataframe? Else, should an apply function be used instead?

Comment: Use lapply with gsub then as.data.fram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution is to convert the data frame to a matrix first then run the gsub and then convert back to a data frame as follows:

```
as.data.frame(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", as.matrix(df)))
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a possible solution using dplyr:

```
# Example data
bla <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), 
              b = c("fefa%^%", "fes^%#$%", "gD%^E%Ewfseges"), 
              c = c("%#%$#^#", "%#$#%@", ",.,gdgd$%,."))

# Use mutate_all from dplyr
bla %>%
  mutate_all(funs(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", .)))

  a           b    c
1 1        fefa     
2 2         fes     
3 3 gDEEwfseges gdgd
```

---

### Update:

`mutate_all` has been [superseded](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/dplyr/html/mutate_all.html), and `funs` is [deprecated](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/funs.html#:%7E:text=funs()%20is%20deprecated%3B%20please,other%20packages%20in%20the%20tidyverse.) as of dplyr 0.8.0. Here is an updated solution using `mutate` and `across`:

```
# Example data
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), 
                 b = c("fefa%^%", "fes^%#$%", "gD%^E%Ewfseges"), 
                 c = c("%#%$#^#", "%#$#%@", ",.,gdgd$%,."))

# Use mutate_all from dplyr
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", .x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I like Ryan's answer using dplyr. As `mutate_all` and `funs` are now deprecated, here is my suggested updated solution using `mutate` and `across`:

```
# Example data
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), 
                 b = c("fefa%^%", "fes^%#$%", "gD%^E%Ewfseges"), 
                 c = c("%#%$#^#", "%#$#%@", ",.,gdgd$%,."))

# Use across() from dplyr
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", .x)))

  a           b    c
1 1        fefa     
2 2         fes     
3 3 gDEEwfseges gdgd
```